# OAuth2 Password Grant Type with Client_Id & Client_Secret

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, token

I am developing an app to access its own resources via Rest endpoints.

Users are required to acquire access token via email/password. After completed Authentication server configuration, I had this observation:

With:

```
curl client:secret@localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password
```

I am getting the correct response:

```
{"access_token":"7541a4f6-e841-41a0-8a54-abf8e0666ed1","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"d3fdd7e3-53eb-4e7b-aa45-b524a9e7b316","expires_in":43199,"scope":"openid"}
```

However With:

```
curl http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password -d client_id=client -d client_secret=secret
```

I am getting the following error:

> DEBUG 4123 --- [nio-9999-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter 
>   : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication
>   entry point
>
> org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is
>   denied    at
>   org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83)

It looks like the client_id & client_secret are not being recognized when send as parameters. Is this a configuration issue or to do with the version of OAuth2 I am using (**spring-security-oauth2**, **2.0.5.RELEASE**)

A lot of example I come across on the Internet suggest approach one should work with OAuth2.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no method of authenticating the Client against the Authorization Server that is mandatory to implement by spec. Two methods that have been specified that MAY be supported are the HTTP Basic Authentication pattern and the HTTP POST parameter pattern that you've used in your examples. Apparently Spring supports only the first, which seems to be supported by the docs at: http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html

Comment: I believe you are mistaken about what the specification mandates.  Please see my alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, lots of examples show the client credentials being passed as form parameters, but it turns out that approach is not recommended, while passing the credentials using "Basic" authentication via the HTTP Authorization header is standard.

[Section 2.3.1 of RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.3.1) says

> The authorization server MUST support the HTTP Basic
> authentication scheme for authenticating clients that were issued a
> client password.

And further says

> Alternatively, the authorization server MAY support including the
> client credentials in the request-body using the following
> parameters:
>
> - client_id ...
> - client_secret ...
>
> Including the client credentials in the request-body using the two
> parameters is NOT RECOMMENDED and SHOULD be limited to clients unable
> to directly utilize the HTTP Basic authentication scheme (or other
> password-based HTTP authentication schemes).

In my experience, however, there are some servers that, in violation of the RFC, will **not** accept HTTP Basic authentication and will only accept form parameters in the body.