# Sending username and password in headers in Spring Security Oauth2

Tags: java, spring, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring Security Oauth2 for generating access token. When I use `password` as grant type, I send a post request as

> http://localhost:8085/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=ws&client_secret=secret&scope=read+write&username=david@abc.com&password=abc@123

I don't want to send the username and password in the URL.

I checked source code of `TokenEndPoint.java` but couldn't find much.  I know that we can use `HTTPS` and encrypt the username and password.

I just want to know if there is any way to send username and password in headers.

Comment: Check this out url you get the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24699978/spring-security-oauth2-resource-owner-password-credentials-grant

Comment: @Rocky I think you din't understand my question, the link you gave is not at all related my question.

Comment: Hey did you find the solution :| as I am also stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you and meets your requirement.

## Source: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/master/docs/oauth2.md

As a general rule, a web application should not use password grants, so avoid using ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails if you can in favour of AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails. If you desparately need password grants to work from a Java client, then use the same mechanism to configure your OAuth2RestTemplate and add the credentials to the AccessTokenRequest (which is a Map and is ephemeral) not the ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails (which is shared between all access tokens).

## OAuth2RestTemplate example in Git Hub

url: https://github.com/mariubog/oauth-client-sample